# Is it possible to set assertions per env in CodeCeption?

Tags: php, bdd, codeception

With Codeception, it is possible to use same test scenario with different data. But is it possible to do customize it per env variable? I could not find any documentation about this.

```
<?php
 /**
  * @example(url="/info", title="Info")
  * @example(url="/about", title="About Us")
  * @example(url="/contact", title="Contact Us")
  */
  public function staticPages(AcceptanceTester $I, \Codeception\Example $example)
  {
    $I->amOnPage($example['url']);
    $I->see($example['title'], 'h1');
    $I->seeInTitle($example['title']);
  }
```

For example, looking to do something like

```
<?php
  /**
  * @env abc
  * @example { "url": "/about", "title": "About Us" }
  * @env xyz
  * @example { "url": "/contact", "title": "Contact Us" }
  */
  public function staticPages(AcceptanceTester $I, \Codeception\Example $example)
  {
    $I->amOnPage($example['url']);
    $I->see($example['title'], 'h1');
    $I->seeInTitle($example['title']);
  }
```

Comment: See if you can declare `@example` as array, store inside an array for each env and read based on a parameter.

Comment: That did not work

Comment: Move the checks inside the method in an array and handle the array in any way you want.